# Is it possible to recreate table schemas from .ibd file only?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

Is there any method to recreate mysql databases only from .ibd files?
It would be great if someone could post a method how to create .frm or get "create table" statements or even restore database fully.

The thing is, that I have used percona's xtrabackup for mysql backups, but unfortunately this tool seems to backup only the data, excluding the schema of database. In my opinion, they should mention this more clearly in their documentation.  So now I have only bunch of .ibd files and need to restore database fully. All tables in databases are with InnoDB engine.

This is command I have used to make a backup:

```
xtrabackup --backup --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/ --target-dir=/backup/
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What did you use to try and restore the backup?

Comment: Hi, for making a backup I have used percona's xtrabackup and for restoring I have used these instructions: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/howtos/recipes_xbk_restore.html

I have to restore the whole database, because server has crashed (hdd went off).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.5/en/partial.restoring.single.html):

```
LOCK TABLES tblname WRITE;
ALTER TABLE tbl DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ALTER TABLE tbl IMPORT TABLESPACE;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Do note the following:

- There cannot be uncommitted transactions in the ibd files.
- There are no unmerged insert buffer entries in the .ibd file.
- Purge has removed all delete-marked index records from the .ibd file
- mysqld has flushed all modified pages of the .ibd file from the buffer pool to the file.

I hope this summary and the documentation helps you sort your problem. If you have further problems, please leave a comment.

Comment: Hi, I get the following: 

    mysql> LOCK TABLES zw WRITE;
    ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'zw.zw' doesn't exist

If I try to create the table I get this:

    mysql> CREATE TABLE zw (`id` int);
    ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'zw.zw' (errno: -1)

Comment: Check permissions for your user

Comment: I am trying to do this with root user.

Comment: `root` on your system may not be `root` on mysql

Comment: Hello, I have checked the permissions and everything seems to be ok, because I am using mysql root, and system root as well. Seems that a problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Do you mind if I poke around the database and try to find out the problem? This shouldn't be this involved.